# Should static_assert really succeed when testing existence of an operator that's declared but not defined?

Tags: c++, templates, boost, static-assert

Why does the `static_assert` below succeed? I have only made the `<<` operator a friend, but I haven't created it anywhere.

```
struct foo {
  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const foo &f);
};

template<typename T>
struct bar {
  //succeeds:
  static_assert(boost::has_left_shift<std::ostream,T>::value, "failure");
};

int main(int,char**) {
  bar<foo> b;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `boost::has_left_shift<std::ostream,T>::value, "failure"` is evaluated before linking, when the actual symbol is looked for.

Comment: A friend declaration is a declaration, so you did in fact introduce the operator in the program.

Comment: @Luc: that's the _answer_!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The friend declaration establishes that the operator exists. If you used it, the compiler would accept it:

```
std::cout << foo();
```

That's all the assertion can test, either. A program with this statement in it probably will not link because you haven't *defined* the operator, but just like the compiler, the assertion cannot detect that. It has no idea whether some other translation unit might eventually provide a definition for that function.

Compiling and linking are separate phases.

If you do provide a definition in another file, and you compile that file, you can then link the two compiled files together to form a complete program. You won't have to recompile the first file. That's what *separate compilation* is all about.